# Langserve Streaming with Llamacpp

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, llama-cpp-python

I have built a RAG app with Llamacpp and Langserve and it generally works. However I can't find a way to stream my responses, which would be very important for the application. Here is my code:

```
from langchain_community.vectorstores.pgvector import PGVector
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, PromptTemplate
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnableParallel
import os
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceBgeEmbeddings, HuggingFaceEmbeddings
import box 
import yaml
from langchain_community.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler
from operator import itemgetter
from typing import TypedDict
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from langserve import add_routes
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from starlette.staticfiles import StaticFiles


with open('./config/config.yml', 'r', encoding='utf8') as ymlfile:
    cfg = box.Box(yaml.safe_load(ymlfile))
    
def build_llm(model_path, temperature=cfg.RAG_TEMPERATURE, max_tokens=cfg.MAX_TOKENS, callback = StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()):
        
        callback_manager = CallbackManager([callback])
        
        n_gpu_layers = 1 # Metal set to 1 is enough. # ausprobiert mit mehreren
        n_batch = 512 #1024 Should be between 1 and n_ctx, consider the amount of RAM of your Apple Silicon Chip.

        llm = LlamaCpp(
                max_tokens = max_tokens,
                n_threads = 8,#8, #für performance,
                model_path=model_path,
                temperature=temperature,
                f16_kv=True,
                n_ctx=15000, # 8k aber mann muss Platz lassen für Instruction, History etc. 
                n_gpu_layers=n_gpu_layers,
                n_batch=n_batch,
                callback_manager=callback_manager, 
                verbose=True, # Verbose is required to pass to the callback manager
                top_p=0.75,
                top_k=40,
                repeat_penalty = 1.1,
                streaming=True,
                model_kwargs={
                        #'repetition_penalty': 1.1,
                        #'mirostat': 2,
                },
        )
        
        return llm

embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name=cfg.EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME,
                                            model_kwargs={'device': 'mps'})

PG_COLLECTION_NAME =  "PGVECTOR_BKB"
model_path = "./modelle/sauerkrautlm-mixtral-8x7b-instruct.Q4_K_M.gguf"

CONNECTION_STRING = "MY_CONNECTION_STRING"
vector_store = PGVector(
    collection_name=PG_COLLECTION_NAME,
    connection_string=CONNECTION_STRING,
    embedding_function=embeddings
)

prompt= """
<s> [INST] Du bist RagBot, ein hilfsbereiter Assistent. Antworte nur auf Deutsch. Verwende die folgenden Kontextinformationen, um die Frage am Ende knapp zu beantworten. Wenn du die Antwort nicht kennst, sag einfach, dass du es nicht weisst. Erfinde keine Antwort! Falls der Nutzer allgemeine Fragen stellt, führe Smalltalk mit Ihm.

### Hier der Kontext: ###
{context}

### Hier die Frage: ###
{question}

Antwort: [/INST]
"""

def model_response_prompt():
    return PromptTemplate(template=prompt, input_variables=['input', 'typescript_string'])
prompt_temp = model_response_prompt()

llm = build_llm(model_path, temperature= cfg.NO_RAG_TEMPERATURE, max_tokens = cfg.NO_RAG_MAX_TOKENS)

class RagInput(TypedDict):
    question: str


final_chain = (
        RunnableParallel(
            context=(itemgetter("question") | vector_store.as_retriever()),
            question=itemgetter("question")
        ) |
        RunnableParallel(
            answer=(prompt_temp| llm),
            docs=itemgetter("context")
        )

).with_types(input_type=RagInput)



app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=[
        "http://localhost:3000"
    ],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

#app.mount("/rag/static", StaticFiles(directory="./source_docs"), name="static")
@app.get("/")
async def redirect_root_to_docs():
    return RedirectResponse("/docs")


# Edit this to add the chain you want to add
add_routes(app, final_chain, path="/rag")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

So if I try it out in the server playground (http://0.0.0.0:8000/rag/playground) the response is not streamed but returned when the completion is done. I only see the streaming in my Terminal.

So does anyone have suggestions what I have to change?